# Is there a way to avoid re-authorization of a bound script after the user has made a copy of the gdoc the script is bound to?

Tags: google-apps-script

I don't really know if this is the right place for the question, I apologize if it is not.

I currently have a gslides presentation which is used as a template to programmatically generate other presentations. The source presentation is duplicated and the new presentation is served to a user.

I've coded a "toolkit" and put in an Apps Script file bound to the original presentation with the purpose to aid the users in their editing. The reasoning is that the copies of the presentation will also have a copy of the script bound to them. Unfortunately, this would require the user to re-authorize the same script every time they generate a new presentation and they wish to use one of the functions in the toolkit.

The users are all under the same gsuite domain.

I'd like to know if I just have to accept this a necessary evil or if there exists a way to allow users re-utilize the same code on multiple presentations while authorizing it only once.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could deploy your script as an Add-On, this way, after your users install and authorize it once they would not have to do it again.

Ask your domain admin if you are able to do so. Add-ons can be published to subsets of users in your organization.

Hope this helps!